# R - auto creating variables from a dataset

Tags: r

I am trying to pass an argument into a function within a function that is derived from an argument of the first function pasted with default values to form the column name I need to value from...

```
dossstudy <- function(x,y){

attach(x)

  USL <- paste("PivSpecs","$",y,"USL", sep = "")
  USL

}
```

USL comes out as "PivSpecs$D1USL" but I need it to not be a string when it passes in the function.

```
ss.study.ca(y, xLT = NA, PivSpecs$LSL, USL, PivSpecs$D1Target, 
          #  alpha = 0.05, f.na.rm = TRUE)
```

so I can run the function like below

```
  dossstudy(cam1,"D1")
```

I have the LSL, USL and target stored in a data frame PivSpecs

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It seems like maybe its worth using the `[[` or `[` notation, but more detail of what your objects are is needed. E.g. return a string "USL" and just pass it to `PivSepcs[["USL"]]`. If you provide more context to the problem its likely there is a far better way.

Comment: As @zacdav says, just do `PivSpecs[[y]]`. And review subsetting in R, you need to grok this before getting into more advanced stuff. Also, it is almost always a bad idea to use `attach`, though we'd need more context to see why you are doing that.

Comment: You can use `get` to get a variable name specified by a string. For example, `MyVariable <- 10`, `VariableName <- "MyVariable"` and then `get(VariableName)` returns `10`.

Comment: So I have an output from a camera that measures distance from a known datum. I would like to run a capability study from the package "SixSigma" to analyse the results from each measure. The measurements are named D1, D2 etc. In order to run the ss.study.ca from SixSigma you need the lower and upper limits plus the target. I generated a dataframe with these specs, with each column labelled D1USL, D1LSL etc and the only value in each column is the value I need to put into the ss.study.ca arguments. there are 7 dimensions I wish to generate the study for so wanted to have a function to automate

Comment: I was using attach so I could then switch between different dataframes which have the same named columns but are from different cameras if that makes sense