# R redefine a string to argument

Tags: r

following on from some help earlier I think all I need for this to work is a way to define the variable dimxST below as not a string as I need that to point to the data frame....

```
cpkstudy <- function(x,y){


  dxST <- paste(x,"$",y, sep = "")

  dLSL <- paste(y, "LSL", sep = "")
  dUSL <- paste(y, "USL", sep = "")
  dTar <- paste(y, "Target", sep = "")

  dimxST <- 
  dimLSL <- PivSpecs[[dLSL]]
  dimUSL <- PivSpecs[[dUSL]]
  dimTar <- PivSpecs[[dTar]]


  ss.study.ca(dimxST, LSL = dimLSL, USL =  dimUSL, Target = dimTar,
              alpha = 0.05, f.na.rm = TRUE, f.main = "Six Sigma Study")

}

cpkstudy("cam1","D1")
```

link to the previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50115330/r-auto-creating-variables-from-a-dataset?noredirect=1#comment87247949_50115330)

Comment: Using `dplyr`, you could write this `dimxST <- get(x) %>% select_(y)`

Comment: Thanks Lyngbakr but I couldn't get that work. For now I have changed the argument x to the column I want to use as the dimxST like this `cpkstudy(cam1$D24,"D24")` and then just declare `dimxST <- x`

Comment: Just to verify `x` is a string naming a data frame or list, and `y` is a string naming element in the df or list named by `x`?  Is there a reason you need to use a string for `x`?

Comment: More generally, can you provide a reproducible example which makes it clear what `cam1` and `D1` are?

Comment: Hi Mellisa, Yeah x is the name of the DF and y the element. Y is also used to 'lookup' the USL/LSL/Tar from another DF called PIvSpecs

Comment: cam1 has 58 columns, where there are 7(D1,D2,D3,D4,D25,D26,D27) I am interested in for the cpk study.In each row(observation) there is a measurement in mm to 4 decimal places. PivSpecs has a column storing 1 observation which is the USL, so D1USL has the observation of 0.65 and so on for each dimension. I have another df cam2 which is formatted the same as cam1 but it is th results from a different camera so the observations are different values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a different direction, and you may find the learning curve a bit steeper, but it's a lot more powerful.  Instead of passing everything in as strings, we pass them without quotes, and use the `rlang` package to figure out where to evaluate `D1`.

```
# the same dummy data frame from Katia's answer
cam1 <- data.frame(D1 = rnorm(10), 
  D2 = rnorm(10))

PivSpecs <- list(D1LSL = 740, D1USL = 760, D1Target = 750)

library(rlang)
cpkstudy <- function(df, y){
  quo_y <- enquo(y)

  dLSL <- paste0(quo_name(quo_y), "LSL")
  dUSL <- paste0(quo_name(quo_y), "USL")
  dTar <- paste0(quo_name(quo_y), "Target")

  dimxST <-  eval_tidy(quo_y, data = df)
  dimLSL <- PivSpecs[[dLSL]]
  dimUSL <- PivSpecs[[dUSL]]
  dimTar <- PivSpecs[[dTar]]


  print(dimxST)
  print (paste("dimLSL=", dimLSL) )
  print (paste("dimUSL=", dimUSL) )
  print (paste("dimTar=", dimTar) )
  # ss.study.ca(dimxST, LSL = dimLSL, USL =  dimUSL, Target = dimTar,
    # alpha = 0.05, f.na.rm = TRUE, f.main = "Six Sigma Study")

}

# notice that I am not quoting cam1 and D1
cpkstudy(cam1, D1)
```

If you want to learn more about this, I would suggest looking at https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html as an overview (the `dplyr` package imports some of the functions used in `rlang`), and http://rlang.r-lib.org/index.html for a more complete list of all the functions and examples.

Comment: Hi Melissa, this method works very well. I will read up on rlang so I can understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `get()` to get object value from its string representation. In this solution I did not evaluate `ss.study.ca()` function itself, since I do not have your real-case input data, instead I just print the values that would go there:

```
cpkstudy <- function(x,y){


  #dxST <- paste0(x,"$",y)

  dLSL <- paste0(y, "LSL")
  dUSL <- paste0(y, "USL")
  dTar <- paste0(y, "Target")


  dimxST <- get(x)[,y]
  print(dimxST)


  dimLSL <- PivSpecs[[dLSL]]
  dimUSL <- PivSpecs[[dUSL]]
  dimTar <- PivSpecs[[dTar]]

  print (paste("dimLSL=", dimLSL) )
  print (paste("dimUSL=", dimUSL) )
  print (paste("dimTar=", dimTar) )

  #ss.study.ca(dimxST, LSL = dimLSL, USL =  dimUSL, Target = dimTar,
  #            alpha = 0.05, f.na.rm = TRUE, f.main = "Six Sigma Study")

}

# create some dummy dataframe to test with this example
cam1 <- data.frame(D1 = rnorm(10), 
                   D2 = rnorm(10))

# define a list that will be used within a function
PivSpecs <- list(D1LSL = 740, D1USL = 760, D1Target = 750)

#test function
cpkstudy("cam1","D1")

#[1]  1.82120625 -0.08857998 -0.08452232 -0.43263828  0.17974556 -0.91141414 #-2.30595203 -1.24014396 -1.83814577 -0.24812598
#[1] "dimLSL= 740"
#[1] "dimUSL= 760"
#[1] "dimTar= 750"
```

I also changed your `paste()` commands on `paste0()` which has `sep=""` as a default.